# How to adjust end_date picker according to start_date picker and vice versa in ionic2?

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to adjust the end date picker according to what the user choose in the start date, and vice versa if the user decide to choose the end date first.
This is my code:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Start Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" ngControl="start" [(ngModel)]="start_date"></ion-datetime>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-label>{{getDate(start_date | date:'MMddy')}} </ion-label>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>End Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" ngControl="end" min="getDate(start_date | date:'MMddy')" ></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

start-date is initialized in the controller as new Date(), the getDate function is:

```
   getDate(date){
     date = date.split('\/');
     date = date[2] + '-' + date[0] + '-' + date[1];
     return date;
   }
```

the label in the previous code:

```
   <ion-label>{{getDate(start_date | date:'MMddy')}} </ion-label>
```

gives a correct result: 2016-29-06 (today's date), but for the end date picker it's not working, although it would work if I edit the min property of the end datetime like this:

```
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" ngControl="end" min="2016-06-29" ></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked, I needed to add curly braces {{}} to the min expression, another way is to use [min] instead of min.

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Start Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" ngControl="start" [ngModel]="start_date" (ngModelChange)="start_boolean=true" min="{{getDate(today | date:'MMddy')}}"></ion-datetime>
   </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="start_boolean">
      <ion-label>End Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" ngControl="end" min="{{getDate(start_date | date:'MMddy')}}"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

and in the TS file:

initialize today var:

```
today: Date = new Date();
```

and the getDate function:

```
   getDate(date){
     date = date.split('\/');
     date = date[2] + '-' + date[0] + '-' + date[1];
     let re = /\//gi;
     date = date.replace(re, "-");
     return date;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another method for getting/storing the start date and use it as the min:

```
getStart(){
    var minDate = getDate(start_date | date:'MMddy');
    return minDate;
}
```

and then change `min` to this:

```
min="getStart()"
```